# Delete cells by a conditions and create a new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the next dataframe in R:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | 1 | 2 | c | 1 |
| c | 3 | 4 | c | 1 | NA | NA |
| b | c | 5 | 6 | c | 1 | NA |

I need to delete the cells values/text before the first "c". The dataframe I need is:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c | 1 | 2 | c | 1 |
| c | 3 | 4 | c | 1 |
| c | 5 | 6 | c | 1 |

Comment: ```as.data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(strsplit(gsub(".*(?=c)|-NA| (?=.*)","", x, perl = T), "-")), ncol = 3)))```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first combine all strings in the columns row-wise, add an empty string " " in front of the strings (for the regex to work), remove all strings before the first "c", then separate them back to individual columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  summarize(concat = gsub("^.+?(?=c)|, NA", "", paste0(" ", toString(pick(everything()))), perl = T)) |> 
  separate_wider_delim(concat, delim = ", ", names = paste0("col", 1:5))

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 c     1     2     c     1    
2 c     3     4     c     1    
3 c     5     6     c     1
```